# Grails - create read only api

Tags: grails, grails-orm, readonly

I would like to limit some of the actions in controllers to be read-only.
Is there any way I could do that?
What I want is the transaction not to save after it is finished, for certain actions.

Any help is appreciated.

We are talking about 1.3.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put logic in method of grails service

```
class MyController {
  def myService

  def myAction = {
    myService.method(params)
    []
  }
  ...
}
```

and mark it as read-only:

```
class MyService {
  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  def method(def patams) { ... }
}
```

Comment: It took me a while to test it but this is it! It's easy, it actually works, I need no code changes and I don't have to worry about stacking withTransaction one on another or creating copies of my domain classes! Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The 'how to make read only domains' is something that comes up now and then on the mailing lists and other places.

The quick answer is: You can't 100% secure against writes.

Various methods to achieve somewhat read only:

1. Use .read() method to get an object, that ensures that you need to explicitly .save() to make item persist.
2. If on sql, you can make a view and make a domain class map to this view, then you cant save (and trying to save will throw errors).
3. Make beforeUpdate() throw exception, thereby stopping the save.
4. Changes to static mapping = {}, but I am not quite sure what to do there, it has been mentioned on the mailing list is all I can remember, google through the nabble list for grails-user if you want to find out.

If your stuff is fairly static an mysql view is a good choice, if you need to query on them, the beforeUpdate() might be the good choice.

You ask for 'read only actions' though, do you mean scaffolded ones? Programmatically disallowing saving in a controller action is not harder than just.. not adding the save (or not modifying the object at all).

Comment: Domains are also used in other APIs which of course can modify them. So changing beforeUpdate is out of the question here. Using view is quite an idea, however I would have to copy all of the domains and create views for all of them. And there's a lot of querying going on in there :/ "Simply do not save" is not a solution. In future someone will make a change which will not get caught in tests [due to a lot of different paths this api can take depending on the data in there] and we can get screwed on production.I need something that will take the burden of programmer to keep the api read only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `withTransaction` method on domain object and set it to rollback only there.

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withTransaction.html

Declarative transaction management is built-in for services, see Grails reference manual, [Declarative Transactions](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/8.%20The%20Service%20Layer.html#8.1%20Declarative%20Transactions). It won't work for controllers, but there is a plugin for that: http://www.grails.org/plugin/transactional-controller

Comment: I am using around 12 different domain objects and it might be so that some of them will be used and some of them not. This api will perform a lot of work dependent on the data in database.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's enough for you, but there is a read method which is read-only as opposed to get http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/read.html

Comment: I read 2-3 objects, the rest is loaded as part of the collection. I am not sure if all of them will be loaded in read-only, is this true? I was not able to find an answer to this online. Also, how to load objects in read only when using dynamic finders or criteria searches?

Comment: First time I have edited someone else, didn't know it needed review. Here is what i wrote:
    Edit:
    
    This is not a read only accessor, it simply reads in the object     without the dual dirty check property list array, meaning changes     done to fields of the object are not auto persisted on request     finish (you disable dirty checking, technically).

Comment: Oliver: but will this work for dynamic finders? I don't think there's an option in there to return not persisted objects.

Comment: there is a read-only option added in grails 2.0 for dynamic finders